# Python Configuration Error when build retrain.py by bazel, following google doc

Tags: tensorflow

I am learning transfer learning according to [How to Retrain Inception's Final Layer for New Categories](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/image_retraining#training_on_your_own_categories) however, when I build 'retrain.py' using bazel, the following error ocures:

The error message is:
    python configuration error:'PYTHON_BIN_PATH' environment variable is not set and referenced by '//third_party/py/numpy:headers'
I am so sorry, I have done my best to display the error image.unfortunately, I failed.
I use python2.7, anaconda2 and bazel0.6.1, tensorflow1.3.

appreciate for your any reply !

Comment: Its normally better to embed the pictures (error message) so that the link is not lost later.

Comment: I am sorry. It's my first time to ask question in stackvoerflow , so it's not familiar for me. Thank you .